# Delimiting by Number of Characters

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, delimiter

I am trying to delimit a 2D array that has no spaces in it. There are supposed to be 88 columns and 148 rows. But right now it's just 148 spaceless rows. The first row doesn't have any numbers and looks like this:

[image: First Row]

---

But there are rows that have numbers like this:
***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************   308.   308.   308.   308.   308.   308.   308.   308.*********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

The goal is to delimit the rows every 7 characters to make 88 columns. The first two breaks would ideally look like this for each of the rows above:

[image: Ideal result]

and when it gets to the numbers in the second row I shared, it should look like this:

'*******', '   308.'

(Doesn't really matter if the spaces in front of, or the period behind, the 308 is lost)

So far I've tried the following, with the file name being a .txt with the 2D array in it.

```
import numpy as np


a = input('Enter file name: \n')
a = np.loadtxt(a, dtype = 'i', delimiter = '\t')
b = [a[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(a), 3)]
```

But I'm getting the following:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************'

I feel like it's probably an easy fix, but I have been spinning my wheels on it. Please help!

Comment: what are you showing us?  An array, or lines of a text file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read through your question a couple of times and it's not entirely clear to me what you want. You might have to reword your question and give more concrete and complete examples.

If I am understanding your question correctly, you want to read in a text file and split the rows into 7-character chunks (though your example of " 308." is not 7 characters long). Numpy is not the ideal package to use for this problem. You can just use native Python methods.

```py
b = []
with open("temp.txt", "r") as f:
    for a in f:
        a = a.rstrip()
        b.append([a[i:i+7] for i in range(0, len(a), 7)])
```

Comment: Hey, My bad! I just made a stackoverflow account today and didn't realize it doesn't pick up asterisks normally. It looked good in the editor but it posted differently. I updated it now.

Comment: The 308. has three spaces in front of it - which I suppose doesn't count as characters, but is how the 7 still applies. It's output from a fortran code.

Comment: I'll give your code a try though! Thanks for helping, even with the wonky post at first  LOL

Answer (score 0):

I would use a regex here:

```
import re
import numpy as np

s = '***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************   308.   308.   308.   308.   308.   308.   308.   308.*********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************'

out = re.findall(r'(\*{7}|[ \d.]{7})', s)
```

*NB. If you don't want the spaces/dots, use `r'(\*{7}|\d{1,7})'`as regex.

Output:

```
['*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '   308.',
 '   308.',
 '   308.',
 '   308.',
 '   308.',
 '   308.',
 '   308.',
 '   308.',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******',
 '*******']
```